# Apache subdomain redirection

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect, subdomain

Helo,

I want to redirect my subdomain to an internal URL.

For example when user types in someaddress.com he should see a homepage

but when xxx.someaddress.com is typed in I'd like to open http://someaddress.com/testpage

How to achieve this?

I already tried with:

```
<VirtualHost *:8089>
    DocumentRoot "c:\app"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost sms.localhost:8089>
    ServerName smslocalhost
    Redirect permanent / http://localhost:8089/testpage
</VirtualHost>
```

Problem is that whatever I type in now, I get redirected to http://localhost:8089/testpage

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your first vhost definition is doing anything so everything is being processed by the second definition. Try

```
<VirtualHost *:8089>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:\app"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost sms.localhost:8089>
    ServerName sms.localhost
    Redirect permanent / http://localhost:8089/testpage
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: From the comments.

```
NameVirtualHost *:8089
```

fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this already. First definition had "ServerName localhost" and the second one had "ServerName sms.localhost". It didn't work.

Comment: You did remember to put an entry for `sms.localhost` in your  `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file didn't you?

Comment: Yes. "127.0.0.1    sms.localhost"

Comment: @Goran: I just tested the exact configuration above on a wamp server and it works exactly as you want.

Comment: When I added NameVirtualHost *:8089 everything started working.